# How to allow Openzeppellin Governance use Gnosis Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Hi I am doing tests with a custom DAO deployed using Openzeppellin Governor and I would like to allow it to have a gnosis safe. I am trying to create a module but it fails to add it (v1.3.0) when trying using the transaction builder. What is the requeriment to a contract be used as module? My last try was https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xae2bb54bc0b4fb4669d9302c7e454a40355fedb6#code, it contains interface with execTransactionFromModule function. Thank you

Comment: please share the transaction where you try to add it as a module

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x1de3416825bec04ce681f2c90669653a44ca12320d2d1beb7ec2c8420d67229b